# Is there a way to edit how this widget loads on my website, to be responsive

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using a code for a GPA Calculator widget to run on my website, it was working fine, but now, it seems that it is changed from the source, and became unresponsive.

I've asked them for a new code with no response from their side.

Now, I'm trying to fix this from my side, and need your help!

Code:

```
<!-- Calculators.tech Widget -->

<div id="ppsWidgetCode" data-calculator-slug="gpa-calculator" data-calculator-keyword="GPA Calculator" data-config=""></div>

<div style="text-align: center; font-size:12px; color:#333;"><p>GPA Calculator provided by <a href="https://www.calculators.tech/gpa-calculator" target="_blank" style="color:#000;" id="ppsLink" rel="noopener noreferrer">calculators.tech</a></p></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.calculators.tech/assets/lib/js/calculator-widget.js"></script>
```

Here is how it looks like:

[image: Text]

Previously, it was more like this:

[image: Text]

I don't want to have this scroll option, I want it to show a complete shape of the calculator.

Is there a way to edit this from my side till I get any response from the calculator developer?

Comment: This can very likely be accomplished with css, but we need to see the markup generated by the script tag. Can you post your website url?

Comment: Thanks! Here is the link for the post mentioned in the question:         
(shorturl.at/fX124)

Comment: Thank link redirected me to the shorturl homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they have removed `height` attribute on iframe. Try this script below which tries to modify height on iframe when it finishes loading

```html
<!-- Calculators.tech Widget -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
  function renderCalc() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('iframe#ifr').css('height', '100%');
    }, 3000)
  }
</script>

<div id="ppsWidgetCode" data-calculator-slug="gpa-calculator" data-calculator-keyword="GPA Calculator" data-config=""></div>

<div style="text-align: center; font-size:12px; color:#333;">
  <p>GPA Calculator provided by <a href="https://www.calculators.tech/gpa-calculator" target="_blank" style="color:#000;" id="ppsLink" rel="noopener noreferrer">calculators.tech</a></p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.calculators.tech/assets/lib/js/calculator-widget.js" onload="renderCalc()"></script>
```

`onload` event fires when DOM elements gets loaded but still there is no way to find when the assets get loaded like images etc of the document embedded in . For mitigating that issue the timer of 3 sec is used

Comment: Thanks @Viney

I tried it but no change, scroll still there.